# mysqlclient installtion error on python3.6 in venv in unix20.0

Tags: mysql, python-3.6

[Link to open the issue image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziunN.png)
When I tried to install mysqlclient using pip in unix inside virtualenv it showed me  MySQLdb/_mysql.c:46:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory. please help me with your suggestions. Thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

had this exact error today. Turns out Python 3.10 hadn't been installed [it was downloaded and made, but sudo make install wasn't done]. Idk if you're active or if this is relevant since it's been a long time, but give it a shot.